# Is there any source for Rosh Hashana Evening Kiddush Nusah Melody (Sfard/ Ashkenazi)

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, music, kiddush

Is there any recorded resource for traditional Ashkenazi Rosh Hashana melody for Evening Kiddush Melody (Nusah) (Sfard/ Ashkenazi)?

Comment: There are many: https://merhav.nli.org.il/primo-explore/search?query=any,contains,%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94&sortby=rank&vid=NLI&mfacet=rtype,include,recethno,1&mfacet=tlevel,include,online_resources,2&lang=iw_IL

Comment: @Kazibácsi I think only one of those is actually kiddush. As far as I know, there is no official melody, although some Chassidic groups might have one. A real old-school Litvak would not use any melody at all.